# Excel: How do I sum specific number of cells to the right of a name throughout an entire sheet?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have a sheet for the whole year and I would like to sum 5 cells to the right of the day for example:

`[Monday][15][61][75][15][17]`

But I would also like to sum the 5 cells to the right of *all* Mondays in the sheet.  My data looks like this:

```
Wednesday   81  32  0   0   88  14
Thursday    120 17  0   0   108 15
Friday      287 13  0   0   66  11
Saturday    201 12  13  12  78  7
Sunday      217 39  0   1   60  30
Monday      300 13  0   10  68  18
Tuesday     76  0   0   0   0   0
Wednesday   103 0   0   8   20
Thursday    128 0   0   0   0   0
Friday      123 8   15  45  45  16
Saturday    250 12  0   1   45  15
Sunday      197 0   0   0   0   0
Monday      312 21  0   26  97  4
Tuesday     299 17  33  0   121 11
Wednesday   327 16  8   4   90  27
Thursday    131 29  32  25  74  29
Friday      260 10  0   10  76  13
Saturday    370 15  8   9   77  24
Sunday      216 43  0   7   161 29
Monday      86  4   88  102 40
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question. Please post some sample data with desired results.

Comment: But the format is as follows for each month. Is there a way to find all 'Monday" cells in a sheet and sum the 6 following cells to the right of it?

Comment: You have said you want to sum 5 cells to the right of Monday and also 6 cells.  You should be able to figure out how to do either using one of the answers below.  Which one you use depends on whether you want one sum of all the numbers to the right of any Monday, or list a sum for each Monday.

Comment: What is your desired result? It's not clear from your sample data? Without letting us understand your issue we can't help:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9999="Monday")*((B1:B9999)+(C1:C9999)+(D1:D9999)+(E1:E9999)+(F1:F9999)))
```

[image]

Adjust this for your columns of interest and adjust the 9999 to match your data.

For the entire sheet:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="Monday")*((B:B)+(C:C)+(D:D)+(E:E)+(F:F)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following only sums if the left column is Monday

```
=IF(A1="Monday";SUM(B1:F1);"")
```

Comment: This only works for a single row.  The question wants the sum for all Monday rows.  You need another step to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t nearly as elegant as what @garys-student suggested, but it does the trick:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";B1:B20);
     SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";C1:C20);
     SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";D1:D20);
     SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";E1:E20);
     SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";F1:F20);
     SUMIF(A1:A20;"Monday";G1:G20))
```

Given that the data is located in cells A1:G20.

[image: Image of data summing all rows with ‘Monday’ in row A]

I1 contains the finished function; G22 sums the sums of columns; H21 sums the sums of the rows; all three cells contain the same result, confirming that I1 works as intended.